# Understanding php reference and static

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I am trying to understand CodeIgniter core basics like loading a class. I was stuck at this:

```
function &load_class($class, $directory = 'libraries', $prefix = 'CI_')
{
    static $_classes = array();

    // Does the class exist?  If so, we're done...
    if (isset($_classes[$class]))
    {
        return $_classes[$class];
    }
     ...
     ... // more code 
     ...
}
```

and then they load class like this:

```
$BM =& load_class('Benchmark', 'core');
```

So my understandig problem is why the use & before function name, why is static used and why ' =& ' is used.. I think they have something in common.
Is $_classes overwriting as empty array each time load_class function is used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function

```
function &load_class($class, $directory = 'libraries', $prefix = 'CI_') { //... }
```

will return a reference instead of value. Which means, when you call the function like this

```
$BM =& load_class('Benchmark', 'core');
```

In this case `$BM` will get a reference of the class `Benchmark`.

Check [References Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

The following variable

```
static $_classes = array();
```

will be Initialized only once and will be kept it's state when the function ends and whenever execution re-enters the function next time, if it sees the variable `$_classes` is already initialized then it won't initialize it again and if it's not Initialized then it'll Initialize it. This is useful when you need to maintain the same state of a variable on subsequent calls but not a global variable yet.

Check [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: It is exactly what I want to hear, thank you!
So $_classes will be initialized once because every time ' =& ' is used, actually is used the same instance?

Comment: Yes, this variable will keep it's state in the function scope.